# Zipping a text file with sha256 hashes seems too efficient

Tags: compression, zip

I have an ASCII-encoded text file where each line has the following structure:

```
XYplorer nn.nn.nnnn [yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss] [S256 S256].zip
         ↑↑ ↑↑ ↑↑↑↑  ↑↑↑↑ ↑↑ ↑↑ ↑↑ ↑↑ ↑↑   ↑64× ↑64×
```

so a line is 177 characters long, 27 characters don't change and the other 150 do, and the two hashes make up 128 of such characters. I also assume that the hashes are basically random text, thus difficult to compress, so

`27/177  = 15.3%` fixed text

`22/177  = 12.4%` changing text

`128/177 = 72.3%` random text

Yet, zipping such file (1854 lines) the standard (right click) way on Windows I achieve a 49% compression ratio, which baffles me because it seems too high/efficient.

Can you explain to me how the random part could be compressed so much?

Comment: You assume that zip compresses text. It doesn't, it compresses bytes. see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) for the deflate method.

Comment: Another point  to make is that a SHA hash has a very limited alphabet (only 16 different characters are ever used) so that helps with compression.  Just because the characters are in a random order doesn't mean they can't be compressed at all.

Answer (score 5):

The key element here is that this is an ascii encoded file.

Thus each character is encoded using 8 bits.
177 × 8 = 1416 bits each line.  However 177 characters dosen't count line endings, in windows a line ending is encoded as "\r\n" (carriage return, line feed) so will use 179 characters per line lending 1432 bits per line.

Your SHA256's are 64 hex digits each. A hex digit could be trivially packed down to use only 4 bits (2^4 = 16) which is half the size.

Let's break it down:

- (27+2)/179 = 16.2% fixed text (assuming infinitly commpressable)
- 22/179 = 12.3% changing text
- 128/179 = 71.5% text that could be encoded using %50 size.

Using that mapping alone I get 128/2 + 22 = 86 bytes or 688 bits.

- 688/1432 = 48% of the original size.

This isn't taking into account any additional compression that could be performed on the changing text, it looks like they are usually ascii numbers, which suffer the same packing losses as ascii hex digits.

To be 100% honest I'm surprised windows zipping dosen't do a better job.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I think it’s a good answer.